# gRPC NodeJS how to get list of all methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc

I want to get a list of all methods (gPRC methods name) for server in gRPC. I didn't find methods or property in NodeJS gRPC references to get list of gRPC methods - https://grpc.io/grpc/node/grpc.Server.html. How can I do this? Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

```
const Service = grpc.load(protoPath).examplePackage.exampleService;
// your methods:
const methods = Object.keys(Service.prototype);
```

I got the solution from [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/49298d20fa330c0acbd04611229171359e5adcec/packages/grpc-native-core/src/client.js#L806)